# grails iframe css height fixed on 150px

Tags: css, grails, iframe

I am migrating web application (checked in few different examples) into *Grails 3 Framework* and I have noticed that in output `<iframe>` css *height* is always set on *150px* each time. My assumption is that it has sometthing with grails to do. I have checked *assets/stylesheets* and appropiate *views/appropiate.gsp* files and it doesn't appear that `<iframe>` *height* was predefined.
It's clear to me that one way is to overwrite in *appropiate.gsp* `<style>` or stylesheet height for iframe, for example

```
.appropiate-class iframe{
       height: 800px;
}
```

however, I want to avoid hardcoded height to be able to have set iframe height depending on parent divs. The version of grails is 3.3.6.

Is `<iframe>` css *height* 150px a common problem with grails, if not then certainly I'm missing something in my files?

Comment: Hard to say, show the code

Comment: You can try e.g use following codes:http://guides.grails.org/creating-your-first-grails-app/guide/index.html

Comment: and try to integrate under any div tag in index.gsp,iframe. As src provide web page as you wish. iframe height is always set to 150px

Comment: I'm not going to go through the tutorial, but if it's just a matter of styling, have you tried the `!important` annotation?